# Twilio TwiML/Twimlet - Hanging up when call is answered

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am trying to set up a number that, when called, will ring another line and, if the timeout passes, will play a audio file. I got this part working with the CallMe twimlet. However, I am trying to figure out a (simple) way that, should the call being forwarded to the other user be picked up, the call will just disconnect and hang up on both parties. Is this possible? What's the best way to accomplish this, if any? I tried using a echo twimlet in the message property with the reject and hangup verb but neither worked...thanks for your help!